# How to make Spyder output only python printouts in Ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, ipython, spyder

I have some python code that runs optimization based on numbers output from fortran code using a simple os.system .out file. Previously I was able to use Spyder to run the python code and in the IPython console only the python print commands would show; this is preferred since the fortran code has lots of print messages that are useless to me but I don't want to go through and comment them out. I switched to a new computer and downloaded Anaconda 4.6.11 and Spyder 3.3.3, and now I can't recreate that situation where only the python code would print.

I've tried changing some settings in the "Run configuration per file" under the Run tab as well as the "Preferences" tab but there's nothing I can find specifically on just outputting the python code to the terminal.

```py
os.system(MachUp.out)
```

I do remember that the fortran code sent its print messages in a regular terminal while the python code kept its print messages in the IPython terminal. Perhaps it's an older version of Spyder that I should use?

Comment: What is the method for invoking the external process? (with arguments, etc).

Comment: Are the Fortran output statements print ..., write(*,... or write(channel,...?  If it is write(channel, open a temporary file for channel and close it at the end of the program.